# How to call LinkedIn Javascript SDK onLoad function from another file

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am planning to use 'Sign in with LinkedIn' feature in my app. I followed React flux app architecture in my previous projects in which I didn't define any functions in index.html.

I read the LinkedIn docs and it says JS SDK has to be defined in the head section of the HTML like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    onLoad:     onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: true
</script>
```

I used to define only the following in HTML doc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to import LinkedIn JS SDK in other js files. If it has to be in the head of the index.html, is there a way to call **'onLinkedInLoad'** function from a different file ?

Thank you!

Comment: What file structure are you trying to use here? It seems to me that if you're doing this all on the front end you're going to concatenate all of your JS later anyway, or at the very least your other JS files will be below it in the HTML doc. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I only leave app.js in the HTML doc. I looked at couple of 'sign in with LinkedIn' examples and they are all defined in HTML doc. However I want to keep my index.html as above.

Comment: So what's your issue? Linked javascript in a separate file is still considered "on the page" as far as scope is concerned.

Comment: I didn't want to define that function in index.html. 
I created it in another file and had to make it global function by using **window.onLinkedInLoad**
I am not sure if it is the best to do it.

Comment: The way you're doing it sounds right to me. Seems like the SDK asks you to define a callback for when the LinkedIn SDK loads and that's exactly what you're doing.